# Example of an algorithm that's in O(f(n)), but not in Θ(f(n))

Tags: time-complexity

What would be an example of an algorithm that's in O(f(n)), but not in Θ(f(n))?

The only thing I could think of, is an algorithm that behaves differently for different problem sizes, such as an algorithm that performs n operations for even problem sizes and n^2 operations for odd problem sizes. Such algorithms are rare in practice though. Is there a more commonly occurring example (preferably a textbook algorithm) that is in O(f(n)), but not  in Θ(f(n))?

**EDIT.** I know that an algorithm belongs to an infinite number of O-classes. We are always interested in the lowest O-class in practice. So, the question is, what is the example of an algorithm whose lowest O-class is not the same as its highest Ω-class?

Comment: Think of Quicksort !

Comment: Also the adaptive sorts, which are $\Omega(n)$ and $O(n\log(n))$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What about QuickSort? Are you confusing my question with worst-case vs. average-case?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning quicksort also has best-case $\Theta(n\log n)$.

Comment: No, I am not...

Comment: Please don't use edits to change the meaning of your question, especially in a way that invalidates existing answers to the original question.  It's vital that you make sure you formulate the original question precisely and accurately.  If you realize that you didn't do that, it is best to ask a new question, not edit the existing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a problem with the formulation of your question, which needs to be corrected before it can be answered.  Algorithms are not in $O(f(n))$ or $\Theta(f(n))$.  Functions can be.

So, now we need to ask what function you are associating with an algorithm.  Normally, when we use big-O notation in algorithm analysis, we are typically looking at the worst-case running time of an algorithm.  (Perhaps you have heard someone say "QuickSort is $O(n^2)$."  If so, that was sloppy wording.  The precise, accurate wording is "the worst-case running time of QuickSort is $O(n^2)$".)

So, I am going to interpret your question as asking for an algorithm whose worst-case running time is in $O(f(n))$ and not in $\Theta(f(n))$.  Such an algorithm is easy to come up with.  For instance, consider MergeSort.  It is in $O(n^3)$ but not $\Theta(n^3)$.

Your edit suggests you are looking for an algorithm whose worst-case running time is in $O(f(n))$, but not $O(g(n))$ for any smaller $g(n)$, and is not in $\Omega(f(n))$.  No such algorithm exists.  Let $T(n)$ denote the worst-case running time of the algorithm.  Then this algorithm's worst-case running time is in $O(T(n))$, but not $O(g(n))$ for any smaller $g(n)$.  It is also in $\Omega(T(n))$ (but not $\Omega(h(n))$ for any bigger $h(n)$).

So the "smallest big-O class" and the "largest big-Omega class" always coincide -- they are exactly equal to the worst-case running time of the algorithm.

Lastly, you might be wondering about algorithms that, on some inputs, run much faster than the worst-case.  There are many examples of that.  For instance, insertion sort runs in $O(n)$ time if its input is already sorted, but in $O(n^2)$ time in the worst case.  QuickSort runs in $O(n \log n)$ time on many inputs, but its worst-case running time is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my terminology. However, I seem to have a counter-example. Consider an algorithm whose running time is $T(n)=n$ when $n$ is odd, and is $T(n)=n^2$ when $n$ is even. We have: (1) $T(n)$ is in $O(n^2)$, but not in $O(n)$ and (2) $T(n)$ is in $\Omega(n)$, but not in $\Omega(n^2)$.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I don't think that's a counter-example.  Let $f(n) = T(n)$.  Then we have $T(n) = O(f(n))$ (which is the lowest big-O class for which this is true), and $T(n) = \Omega(f(n))$ (which is the highest big-Omega class for which this is true), and those coincide.   If you mean to ask the question when $f(n)$ is restricted to be of the form $n^c$ for some $c$, that's a different question and would be worth posting separately, but you've already got the answer to it -- for that question, you have articulated a valid counterexample.

Comment: Thank you, this is eye-opening. However, I am still confused. When analyzing an algorithm for practical purposes, we are interested in $O(f(n))$ only for minimal $f(n)$. Similarly, we are interested in $\Omega(f(n))$ only for maximal $f(n)$. Since the two must coincide as you proved, is there any practical benefit for having two separate notations?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, yes, computer scientists have found it helpful to have both notions, for the same reasons that it is useful to have both the notion of $\le$, $\ge$, and $=$ (which correspond to $O$, $\Omega$, and $\Theta$).

Comment: Additionally, if we talk about an algorithm's running time without specifying the case (worst/average/best), then I think it comes out that the minimal $O(f(n))$ corresponds to the worst case, while the maximal $\Omega(g(n))$ corresponds to the best case. In this context (unlike when talking about a specific case), $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ may not coincide. Is this correct?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I would recommend thinking about it in different terms.  The worst-case running time, best-case running time, and average-case running times might all be asymptotically different (they can differ by a very large amount, potentially).  When you talk about "minimal O...", I suspect you might be interested in learning about big-$\Theta$ notation.

Comment: By "minimal $O(f(n))$", I meant $O(f(n))$ with the lowest $f(n)$ as we had throughout this discussion. I used to think that the distinction between $O$, $\Theta$ and $\Omega$ is orthogonal to the distinction between worst, average and best cases. However, it now seems not so. Namely, $O(f(n))$ with the lowest $f(n)$ describes the running time of the algorithm in the worst case, while $\Omega(f(n))$ with the highest $f(n)$ describes the running time of the algorithm in the best case.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I understand.  At this point if you have further questions you'd like answered, I suggest posting a new question, as this site isn't designed for running conversations or interactive back-and-forth.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the maximum value in an array of length $n$ is in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$, but not in $\Theta(n^2)$. It is however in $\Theta(n)$.

The reason is that $\mathcal{O}$ only gives an upper bound. Since finding the maximum value can be done in linear time, the complexity is in $\mathcal{O}(f(n))$ for any $f$ that grows more quickly than $n\mapsto n$.

Comment: Please see the edit in the question.

Comment: Please ask a new question in a new post instead.

Answer (score 1):

Take any textbook algorithm, and let $g(n)$ be its worst case running time on inputs of size $n$.
Define $f(n) = n \cdot g(n)$.

Since $g(n) \le f(n)$ the algorithm runs in time $g(n) = O(f(n))$.
Moreover, the algorithm does not run in time $\Theta(f(n))$ because it is false that $g(n)= \Omega(f(n))$, as it can be seen by considering $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(n)}{n \cdot g(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0.$$

Comment: Please see the edit in the question.